# What's the best way to secure a top mount stainless steel sink, if the supplied clips don't work?

Tags: sink, caulking, kitchen-sink, water-damage

The clips under my kitchen sink are terrible.  It's impossible to get them tight, and as result it's hard to keep the top caulked, and I now have water damage.  The clips in question were from a Realtor special renovation, and look like:

[image: Top mount sink clip screw cheap]

The head goes into a track that's part of the sink:
[image]

I think it's called a U-Channel sink.

The problems include that the bottom screwdriver slot strips, the screws are hard to turn, and the tighter you get them the more the entire thing wants to tilt away from vertical.  I've tried to get this right a half dozen times, and the best I do is get half the clips to actually bite.

Comment: which part of the clip is supposed to engage with the benchtop?  maybe screw some shallow metal L channel to underside of the benchtop to hook that little toe into,

Comment: How easily does it move inside the track before you start tightening? If it doesn't move freely you might need another set with a smaller head, you could try the ones Home Depot sells from Elkay sink company.

Comment: Did you put something *under* the sink rim to seal it?  This will also help hold it in place. If you use Adhesive Caulk it will be strong, maybe too strong and you will damage the counter if you ever need to remove the sink. Some people will recommend plumber's putty, but it can dry and crack over time.

Comment: looks like the counter top is too thick for those clips/screws. I rigged one in an old apartment i had with 4 small cheap fake vice-grips from harbor fright.

Comment: The screws are only mid way engaged with the countertop, so not too thick.  The pointy tip of the black metal is supposed to dig into the countertop bottom, but generally fails to.

The sink had silicon caulk, replacing plumbers putty which had failed.  The silicon is now failed.

Comment: Is that really a left-handed screw thread or is the photo reversed?